# Passing Values To JS With HTMLButton Generated With PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have some forms that ajax and jquery load into the page from a PHP script.

But a problem arises with the `onclick=` event generated with the PHP.

The error only fires when the button is clicked.

And I'm fairly sure that the page's native JS is fine.

I'm pretty sure there is an error with this php generated line.

```
<button type="button" class="button" value="Add" onclick="Mail_M_Plex(0,"Add");" name="Action">Add</button>
```

Here is what the browser sees after the page loads

```
<button type="button" class="button" value="Add" onclick="Mail_M_Plex(0," add");"="" name="Action">Add</button>
```

why is `=""` added and `Add` changed to lower case `add`?

This is the error`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } line 2`

My question what should be done to call `Mail_M_Plex(0,"add");` when the button is pressed?

Here is the full PHP print out

```
$Output = 
'<tr>'.
'<td><input name="Email" type="Email" id = "0Email" value="" required placeholder="Mark@Smith.com" ></td>'.
'<td><input name="FName" type="text"  id = "0FName" value="" required placeholder="Mark"></td>'.
'<td><input name="LName" type="text"  id = "0LName" value="" required placeholder="Smith"></td>'.          
'<td><button type="button" class="button" value="Add" onclick="Mail_M_Plex(0,"Add");" name="Action">Add</button>'.  

'</td>'.

'<td></td>'.
'</tr>';
echo($Output);
```

Here is the html that it loads into,

```
<tbody id="PartyEmails"> </tbody>
```

Comment: Show us the part of the code that generates that button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use single quotes like this :

```
<button type="button" class="button" value="Add" onclick="Mail_M_Plex(0,'Add');" name="Action">Add</button>
```

Comment: this is absolutely wrong. you are trying to use php inside html without starting the php tags <?php ?>. that's the main problem. It is not going to work

Comment: Sorry for deleting I didn't know you had commented. If you read the post the button is generated in php as text so there is not need to do that.

Comment: can you please add the whole code. So that i can understand better

Comment: I have it working now `'<td><button type="button" class="button" value="Add" onclick="Mail_M_Plex(0,\'Add\');" name="Action">Add</button>'.  `

I just needed to use ` \ ` in front of the ` ' ` that I need to use

Comment: the buttons are in HTML not in php . IF you want to generate the buttons dynamically. then you have to echo the whole HTML for a button

Comment: nice :) this concept is called escape character

Comment: Thankyou I didnt think of the double quote thing because I didn't see the error with PHP highlighting.

Answer (score 3):

You have double quotes within double quotes.  You can use single quotes instead

```
onclick="Mail_M_Plex(0,'Add');"
```